# codeigniter remove index from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

First of all i already did my homework using google.But dont have any idea about htaccess that's why i tried all possible solution.
So don't consider this question as duplicate.

```
Codeigniter version : 3.1.3
Php version :5.6.29
Os : debian 8
Web server : apache2
```

Problem : 
if i am access default_controller route its working fine but if i am trying access any other route than its need index.php

Want to access :

```
http://<ip>/folder_name/<route>
```

Working :

```
http://<ip>/folder_name/index.php/<route>
```

Config variables :

```
base_url =http://<ip>/folder_name/ //showing default controller and working fine.

$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Path:

```
Your_website_folder/
application/
assets/
system/
.htaccess <——— this file
index.php
```

Tried *.htaccess*

1.[Get from codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

2.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Tip: Don't have ip in your url set  your url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';` reason some links and assets will not work if base url not set.

Comment: Try some of these htaccess https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once inside *`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`*  find the following section, and change the line that says AllowOverride from None to All. The section should now look like this:

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//replace with the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.i already tried but didnt get success.so that's why i set AUTO which will check for all possible ways

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file in root directory and rewrite rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Don't use index.php in your any URL. Use directly base URL

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">dashboard</a>